# dash-plotly 3d scatter: uirevision property doesn't keep the viewpoint consistent

Tags: python, plot, plotly-dash

I'm trying to keep the viewpoint consistent in my plotly-dash web app after every callback. This should be straightforward according to many already answered questions. The following line of code should do the magic:

```py
fig.update_layout(uirevision='constant')
```

Unfortunately for me, it looks like that this is not the case for 3D scatter plots, here is a very brief piece of code that should allow to reproduce my problem:

```py
import plotly.express as px
df = px.data.iris()

import dash
from dash import dcc
from dash import html
from dash import Input, Output

app = dash.Dash()
app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Dropdown(['option1', 'option2', 'option3'], 'axis', id='x-dropdown', clearable=False),
    dcc.Graph(id='main-plot')
])
@app.callback(
    Output('main-plot', 'figure'),
    Input('x-dropdown', 'value'))
def update_figure(x_selector):
    fig = px.scatter_3d(df, x='sepal_length', y='sepal_width', z='petal_width',  color='species')
    fig.update_layout(uirevision='constant')
    return fig
    
app.run_server(debug=True, use_reloader=False)
```

This is what i'm observing:
[image: unexpected behavior]

I can tell that the `uirevision` is doing something since the viewpoint is not completely reset after the callback, but it is still very imprecise. Is there something I'm missing or is this the expected behavior?

Comment: Got the same behavior here.. It looks like a bug with the propagation of zoom events, panning doesn't seem affected. This is difficult to track as both types of interaction alter the 3 coords of the camera. I will come back tomorrow if I find something.

Comment: i'm gonna open a ticket on plotly github, thanks for confirming this! https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py/issues/3951